# Credential Storage for Partner/Vendor Accounts

Tags: encryption, passwords

We work with many other companies to do data exchange. As an example, we might work with COMPANY A to send them sensitive data over SFTP. This would be done by them giving us an SFTP Host/Account/Password. We configure our side for the connection and have a process to push those on an interval.

My question is not about how we store that in our application, but rather, if/how those credentials should be stored in case of need for future reference. We typically put those in a password manager like KeePass, which is in our own network in the office behind locked doors on computer that require passwords, access/permissions and another password for KeePass.

Is it considered ok to store such usernames and passwords in this manner if it's been provided by another company, but for us to connect to them? Or is there some reason we should enter the info into our app and never see it again without asking them to verify it themselves?